# Help me understand functions in my Haskell ghci configuration file

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

My xp box uses Haskell Platform, version 6.12.3

I include the following in my .ghci file.

```
:def test \_ -> return $ ":load c:\scripts\haskell\test.hs"
```

Now I can compile and load my test.hs script by entering `:test`. However I can also use `:t, :te or :tes`. I presume this is the Haskell idiom called pattern matching. Unfortunately, my :test command now prevents the use of `:t` as the short form of the Haskell command `:type`.

How can I invoke a function with an entire word that starts with a "t", such as "test" that won't interfere with the `:t` alias of `:type`?

Comment: That's *not* pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an alias for a command with `:def`.

```
:def t return . (":type "++)
```

> How can I invoke a function with an entire word that starts with a "t", such as "test" that won't interfere with the `:t` alias of `:type`?

So far we've been talking about GHCi commands.  Function names don't start with a colon and there's no auto-completion of partial function names.

Answer (score 4):

In your question, you confuse two separate things: *GHCi commands*, which start with a colon and allow you to interact with GHCi as it's running; and *Haskell functions*, which have ordinary names and which you can run within GHCi (but which can't, generally speaking, query it).  Any Haskell tutorial will help you with ordinary functions; for GHCi commands, the best reference is probably [the GHC manual's section on GHCi](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/ghci.html); there's even [a subsection just about commands](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html).

I think that [Heatsink's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227230/help-me-understand-functions-in-my-haskell-ghci-configuration-file/4227419#4227419) is the best for recovering the use of `:t`; GHCi tries to help you out by figuring out what the command's a prefix of and running that instead, so if it guesses wrong, you'll just have to tell it what you mean.  Note that this has *nothing* to do with pattern matching.  Pattern matching has to do with writing Haskell functions which inspect data via constructors, such as

```
null :: [a] -> Bool
null []    = True
null (_:_) = False
```

Comment: As I recall, ghci's behavior is to pick whichever command matching the prefix is alphabetically first.

Comment: That certainly seems to be what's happening; I meant "wrong" in the sense of "…but I don't want that choice!"

Answer (score 0):

From "Learn You a Haskell" 's starting out chapter.

"The interactive mode is invoked by typing in ghci at your prompt. If you have defined some functions in a file called, say, myfunctions.hs, you load up those functions by typing in :l myfunctions and then you can play with them, provided myfunctions.hs is in the same folder from which ghci was invoked. If you change the .hs script, just run :l myfunctions again or do :r, which is equivalent because it reloads the current script."

I'm kind of confused as to why you did what you did in the first place? Can you explain? It's not that much more effort to type an extra .hs

```
test.hs
```

Doing it this way also has the benefit of reminding you that you loading a file.